# Lambda calculus expression reduction

Tags: lambda, expression, reduction

I'm trying to learn and understand how lambda calculus reduction works. I've been reducing some expression and I've run into this one:

```
(λ x . x (λ x . λ y . x))
```

I have reduce it to this:

```
(λ x . λ y . x)
```

But, I don't know if it's in normal form or it can be reduced more.

Comment: If this Python language question, you should add Pyton tag to the question.

Comment: It's a general lambda expression reduction question, not only for Python.

Comment: Could be also suitable for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The first expression cannot be reduced further, as the only term being applied to another term is a bound (and thus undefined) variable.  Your reduction is invalid, as `x` could be anything, and thus we do not know what it will do to `(λ x . λ y . x)`.

Comment: @Saturnino Yes, that is also wrong.  I don't know what you think you're doing.

Comment: It can be reduced if I apply alpha conversión?

Comment: @Saturnino Alpha conversion isn't really reduction; it's just a superficial change of variable names.

Comment: so this lambda expression: (λ f . λ x . f (f x)) can't be reduced?

Comment: Ok, one last question. The expression:  ((λ x . λ y . λ z . z x y) a c), can be reduced more than:  (λ z . z a c)?

Comment: @Saturnino: Yes, it reduces to (λ z . z a c) and can't be reduced any more.